# Is there a way to improve dynmically created html compile?

Tags: angularjs

so i have a situation where in i'm creating html using jquery. I have no choice in this matter since I'm forced to use an old jquery plugin and integrate the created html in angular and the only way to do that is $compile. basically the flow is

```
var createbody = function(htmlcontents,scope){
   $compile(htmlcontents)(scope);
}
```

the company internal jquery plugin is some sort of endless scroll for a table where it destroys and recreates a chunk of the tr's depending on the scroll position. so everytime you scroll, if the plugin needs to destroy and add tr's, createbody gets called.

the problem is that the scroll gets really laggy whenever it does the destroy and create part because of the compile. a directive is not an option at this point.

question: is there a way to cache the previously compiled chunk and use that later on whenever the plugin decides it needs to use that chunk again.? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse compiled template:

```
var compiledTemplate = $compile(html);
compiledTemplate($scope1);
compiledTemplate($scope2);
compiledTemplate($scope3);
```

You can also see how ngRepeat reuses elements: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L469, but it's a bit more complicated.